# Set the permissions on the teamsite as simple as possible

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I have 4 pages on the top link bar. On every page are multiple lists. I would like to setup my teamsite that everyone can view (permission: READ) the pages and see the content of all the lists on the page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add "Everyone" to the Team Site Visitors group. Visitors have only read permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sure if i understood your question

Site Settings => Persons and group => Add the group "Everyone" to the "Visitors Group"